# Extract contents of nodeChildArray in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsdictionary

Im a newbie trying to hack a weather app together. The app pulls down data from a weather api and uses a XPath parser along with `libxml2` to grab the data. I have sorted most of the data apart from the icon url which is contained within a `nodeChildArray`.

`xnodes` is an `NSMutableArray` which contains the following data for each day of the week:

```
nodeChildArray = (
    {
        nodeContent = "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0003_white_cloud.png";
    }
);
nodeName = weatherIconUrl;
```

What I want to do is grab the url from the nodeContent node within the nodeChildArray
This is what I have so far.

```
for ( NSDictionary *node in xnodes ) 
{
    for ( id key in node ) 
    {
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"nodeChildArray"]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Key output %@",key);                                                                                     
        }
    }
}
```

How do I drill down the keys so to speak?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, pretty simple really

```
NSString *url = [[[[xnodes objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"nodeContent"];
```